# How to get the text randomly from the string array?

Tags: android, arrays, loops, android-arrayadapter

I want to get text value randomly values from the string array on the click event, with the using the Text Field (AutoCompleteTextView).

java file here:

```
String[] questionsOpt = { "I just ejaculated blood", "I just eat", "I just emptied my 401k", "I just exist", 
        "tattooed my face", "threw up yellow stuff", "threw up in my mouth", "took a huge dump"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, questionsOpt);

    AutoCompleteTextView actvDev = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvDev);
    actvDev.setThreshold(1);
    actvDev.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

How to add here loop for randomly find string value from the string array on button click event??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
Random random = new Random(); // or create a static random field...
String randString = questionsOpt[random.nextInt(questionsOpt.length)];
```

Comment: tnx for help Binyamin Sharet